# How can i change the design in Cuba Platform?

Tags: css, scss-mixins, cuba-platform

Hello i just started with CUBA and need some help with the design.
I want to change some default design values and colors of the current hover theme of my project.
Already tried to change some values in the xxx-hover-default.scss and xxx-hover-default-ext.scss file, but nothing happened. Not even after stopping the server. Anybody here who has an idea, what i forgot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to redeploy the theme and clear the local browser cache? There is a special task for theme redeploy: `deployThemes` in `build.gradle`.

The theme customization process is described in the documentation here: https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-7.2/web_theme_extension.html

Also please consider the Helium theme plugin, it allows you to change some settings without application reload.

Comment: Agree with using Helium addon. It is more modern and configurable theme, should be used for new projects.